# Close SQLite database connection without closing the console window

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to close the connection to a database after calling .open on it which does not close your console?

I want to keep in memory my previous commands.

Comment: Talking about the `sqlite3` program? Aren't you running it from an existing open terminal session?

Comment: Yes, sqlite3.exe terminal. Just running the exe directly.

Comment: Well, don't do that.

Comment: Well, I am surprised, it still remembers my previous commands when I startup the exe again. But I still have to do an extra command to startup the exe again. So there is no command that will close the DB without exiting the exe?